# A necessary condition for the solvablity of two functional equations

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

This appears in the proof of Charpit's method for solving nonlinear first order PDEs:

Consider the two equaions:
$$f(x,y,z,p,q)=0,\qquad \qquad (1)$$
$$g(x,y,z,p,q)=0,\qquad \qquad (2)$$
where $f$ and $g$ are both smooth.
In Ayers' book "Differential equations", chapter 30, it is stated that:

for the equations (1) and (2) 
to be solvable for $p$ and $q$  we must have 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \\ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial q}   \notag
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0.$$

This is clear when both $f$ and $g$ are linear in both variables $p$ and $q$. What about the general case ?

Thanks a lot